# How to handle asynchronous call in javascript - print numbers with delay using promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am trying to create a function which displays numbers 1 to 10 and prints each number by delay. Like print 1 after 1 second, 2 after 2 seconds upto 10. Also have to print start and end before the number printing and after.

Trying to create a promise and use async await to achieve this. However not able to print correctly "end" after the function.

When trying to resolve the promise, it is getting resolved before the settimout operation.

```
async function disp(){
    console.log("start")
    await promise();
    console.log("end")
}

function promise(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        for(let i=1;i<10;i++){
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(i);
            }, i*1000);
        }
        //resolve();
    })
}


disp();
```

Comment: `await promise()` never returns because promise is never resolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Promise is not settling i.e It is neither `resolving` or `rejecting` so it gonna stay in `pending` state. All you have to do is to settle the promise after `i` reaches the final count

```js
async function disp() {
    console.log('start');
    await promise();
    console.log('end');
}

function promise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const upto = 10;
        for (let i = 1; i <= upto; i++) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(i);
                if (i === upto) resolve();  // CHANGE
            }, i * 1000);
        }
    });
}

disp();
```

Answer (score 4):

A cleaner solution would be to implement a `wait` function. Then you can write more readable code.

```js
const wait = async ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function disp() {
  console.log("start");
  await count(10);
  console.log("end");
}

async function count(n) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    await wait(1000);
    console.log(i);
  }
}

disp();
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, with fewer functions, @gre_gor's solution would look like this:

```js
async function disp(n) {
  console.log("start")
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    console.log(i);
  }
  console.log("end")
}

disp(10);
```